# If an integer $a$ is not divisible by an integer $b$, could this imply that $b = 0$?

Tags: integers

I am working on a proof in advanced mathematics, and I believe my professor may have overlooked something. The proof is that if $d|a$, $d|b$, and $d\not|c$, then  $ax+by=c$ has no integer solutions for $x$ and $y$. However, if $x$, $y$, and $c$ are $0$, that would be an integer solution.

Comment: Without knowing the specifics, it's very hard to say.  However, it seems unlikely to be the right argument to make.

Comment: b could be zero.  But it is not implied.  And therefore can't be implied by that alone.  So the answer to your question is technically No.

Comment: I can imagine a case where one concludes $b\not \mid a $ but it's never stated b is nonzero.  And I suppose one might have a case where $b\not \mid a $ and b nonzero are incompatible .  I think $\gcd (a,b) = a $ and $b \not \mid a $ and $|a| \ge |b|$ would together imply that $b=0$.  But it's late and I make dumb mistakes when it is late.

Comment: Everything divides 0.

Comment: If $c=0$ then $d|c $.

Answer (score 2):

$d|0$.  Everything divides $0$.